# ExtJs Tranlsated combobox values

Tags: extjs, combobox, store

I have a combo box which listens to a store

```
        {
                                id: 'filterOrderStatus',
                                xtype: 'combobox',
                                fieldLabel: Translation.MailboxListStatus,
                                store: 'DocumentStatuses',
                                displayField: 'name',
                                valueField: 'id',
                                itemId: 'filterOrderStatus',
//                                flex: 1,
                                height: 23,
                                labelWidth: 45,
                                width: 130,
                                cls: 'filterInputField',
                                listConfig: {
                                    cls: 'comboboxlist-sizefit'
                                }
```

The store is a simple  ajax store which retrives values. nwo i need to convert the values which he gets into a another language, how could i do that?? here is the store:

```
Ext.define('xxx.xx.xxx', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires: 'xxx.xxx.xx',
    model: 'xxx.xxx.xxxx',

    autoLoad: true,

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        api: {
            read: ConfigurationData.url + 'xxx.php?xx=xx&xx=xxx'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'results',
            successProperty: 'success'
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model you could return the converted record directly as shown

```
{
  name : 'name',
  convert : function( value, record ) {
               //Your logic to convert the old name(value) into new name.
               return name;
   }   
   type: 'string'
},
```